# How to remove a URL from my XML sitemap?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I have installed the [XML sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module and included all my articles in the sitemap. By default, also the URL **node/add/article** is added, but I do not want that since anonymous users cannot visit this page. Google's Search Console tells me that the URL is blocked by **robots.txt** - which is great - but I want to get rid of the warning messages that show up due to the blocking.

How can I delete the URL **node/add/article** from my sitemap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could either happen because it's node/add/article is included within a menu that's indexed by XML Sitemap or a custom path that was added.

In either case, a drush command can update the path flag for exclusion & rebuild the sitemap so that it's no longer there.

```
drush sqlq "UPDATE xmlsitemap SET status = 0 WHERE loc = 'node/add/article'"
drush xmlsitemap-rebuild
```

If you need to do this through the UI, you'll need to check either **/admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/custom** for a custom link or edit the menu item that contains it (**/admin/structure/menu**).